# How to find the indexes of the last row by ID?

Tags: r, indexing

If my dataframe df is this:

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | 9 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |

I want to perform actions on the last row by ID, but for that I need to find the indexes of those rows. In this example, I wanted to find indexes 4 and 7, which are the indexes of the last row from ID 1 and 2, respectively, in order to then create a new column where I summed the X and Y variables from those indexes. The desired output is below:

| ID | X | Y | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | NA |
| 1 | 6 | 5 | NA |
| 1 | 8 | 4 | NA |
| 1 | 9 | 6 | 15 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 | NA |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | NA |
| 2 | 3 | 9 | 12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach may look like so:

```r
d <- data.frame(
          ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
           X = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 3L),
           Y = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L)
)

library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(row_number() == last(row_number()), X + Y, NA)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>      ID     X     Y   new
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4     6    NA
#> 2     1     6     5    NA
#> 3     1     8     4    NA
#> 4     1     9     6    15
#> 5     2     6     4    NA
#> 6     2     7     5    NA
#> 7     2     3     9    12
```

Answer (score 3):

Use any of the definitions of `is_last` below.  This uses only base R but could also work with dplyr by replacing transform with mutate.

They should all work with the data shown in the question but if the data differs there would be differences and which one to use would depend on what you want.  `findInterval` assumes that the  ID's are in ascending order.  If the ID's do not appear consecutively then the `duplicated` and `ave` solutions mark the last one found in the last contiguous group of each ID whereas the `rle` solution marks the last one in each contiguous group.

```
is_last <- function(x) !duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
is_last <- function(x) findInterval(x, x) == seq_along(x)
is_lsat <- function(x) seq_along(x) %in% cumsum(rle(x)$lengths)
is_last <- function(x) !!ave(x, x, FUN = function(z) seq_along(z) == length(z))

transform(df1, new = ifelse(is_last(ID), X+Y, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what if I only wanted a vector with the indexes of the last row by ID? In this case, a vector with the indexes 4 and 7?

Comment: Try `which(is_last(df1$ID))` or `na.omit(tt$new)` where `is_last`  is given in the answer and `tt` is the result of `transform(...)` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)[,new:=fifelse(1:.N==.N,X+Y,NA_real_),by=ID][]

   ID X Y new
1:  1 4 6  NA
2:  1 6 5  NA
3:  1 8 4  NA
4:  1 9 6  15
5:  2 6 4  NA
6:  2 7 5  NA
7:  2 3 9  12
```